# How to implement Algolia date wise refinement?

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch, react-instantsearch

How to implement Algolia date refinement as shown below in the image?
[image]

All records have an arrival date. based on that, If user clicked last 7 days, I want to filter the products that have created date less than equal a week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this with Algolia, but it requires storing your dates as Unix timestamps within your index. Then you can filter on date ranges across the time stamps.

Here's an example:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/how-to/filter-by-date/

Comment: can you provide further information on this? i'm using algolia instantsearch.js and it's not clear how using filters works with their front end ui component.